# FFMPEG YUV extraction: missing frames

Tags: ffmpeg, yuv, libyuv

I've tried to extract YUV frames from TS/m4v file using FFMPEG.
I've found that all the frames displayed prior to first decoded frame are not extracted.
usage: ffmpeg -i

Is there a method to extract these frames?
Is there another method to extract YUV?

BTW, by first transcoding and than extracting YUV, I get these frames.
The point is that I need the original YUV and not the transcoded one.

Thanks

Comment: ffmpeg is a constant moving target, which version did you use? `ffmpeg -i file.mp4 frames.yuv` never failed me sofar.

Comment: I'm using FFMPEG 2.1.4
The problem is limited to a few frames in the first GOP,
Whose presentation time is prior to IDR's presentation time.

The Problem is consistent and easily reproducible.
@FredrikPihl